# How do I return a purchase from the Ubuntu Software Centre?

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I purchased Amnesia (game) from the Ubuntu Software Centre. It crashes on startup every time and I therefore want to return it for a refund. I can't find a way of doing so through the USC and, strangely, I can't find any trace of this having been asked before (maybe bad googling on my part). So the question is: how do I return a purchase and get a refund through the USC?

EDIT
Installing proprietary driver for AMD catalyst fixed Amnesia, but I still think this is an important question because it's basic customer service for any purchase. I'd therefore appreciate any answers anyone can find and I will continue to look too. If I find the answer I'll post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Ubuntu Software Centre Terms of Service](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/tos/) clause 3 a :

> Payment for apps is due at the time you purchase the app. You will be asked to enter your credit card number and we will charge your credit card at the time of purchase. Fees are charged in the currency in which you make your purchase. All fees are non-refundable.

Comment: Thanks Samik. I must say I'm slightly disappointed with those terms of service, and I'm not sure they're compatible with either the 1979 Sale of Goods Act http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1979/54 or the distance selling regulations http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2000/2334/contents/made in the UK (which entitle someone to a refund if the goods they bought aren't fit for purpose or even if they change their mind soon after purchase). I can understand resisting refunds for changes of mind, but if you sell something that doesn't work it's just bad service not to allow returns.

Comment: I think this issue should be brought to the notice of Canonical. They must have considered the issue and has an explanation for this.

Comment: Good point. I'll look for an appropriate message board/email address tomorrow. I agree they'll probably have thought of this, so I'll be interested to find out what their explanation is.

Comment: Software is typically non-returnable once open or used. Do stores in the UK let you carry in opened boxed software for full refunds? If you purchase a downloadable game from such a store, say Amazon.co.uk, can you return it for a full refund?

Comment: @izx yes the merchant has no option if the goods they sold weren't fit to perform the purpose for which they sold them.

Comment: @GarryCairns : I suggest you find out why Amazon UK doesn't seem to [abide by that then](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=13036701)

Comment: @izx According to the link you provided they do abide by it. They link to specific guidance for damaged and defective goods, which is entirely in keeping with the 1979 Act, from that page. The link in question is http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=1161016

Comment: @GarryCairns But that leads to http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=1161002, which reiterates that Music, Software, etc. must be *New, unopened*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3638/discussion-between-garry-cairns-and-izx)

Comment: Email Canonical or the developer directly. If that doesn't work, there's always the Small Claims Court to compel them to issue a refund.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a link to the official [FAQ about purchases and refund](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pay/FAQs/Refunds), which means you can get a refund. You just have to write an email to pay-support@canonical.com with the purchase receipt.